# When did the Catholic Letters get called the Catholic Letters

Tags: bible, terminology, epistles

The Catholic Encyclopedia says which [books are the Catholic Letters](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03453a.htm) but doesn't say how long ago it was that they were called that.  I was wondering, because of another post asking for the oldest instance of the term Catholic.  Did St. Jerome or Eusebius ever call them that, was it written in the Codex Vaticanus or the Book of Kells or what?

Comment: @Peter Turner perhaps you'll find this transcript/talk as interesting as I do :-) http://www.ancientfaith.com/podcasts/statutes/introduction_to_the_catholic_epistles

Answer (score 2):

The word Catholic (*katholikos* from *katholou* — throughout the whole, i.e., **universal**) cf. [CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: Catholic](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03449a.htm)

> **The Catholic Letters**  After the thirteen letters of St. Paul and the letter to the *Hebrews* come seven other letters (one by St.
>   James, two by St. Peter, three by St. John, and one by St. Jude)
>   **which since the time of Origen, Eusebius and St. Jerome have been
>   known as 'catholic' letters, letters to the Church at large**, not
>   directed to a particular church or individual: the second and third
>   letters of St. John, even though they are addressed to a private
>   individual are regarded as appendixes to his first letter and are also
>   included in the 'catholic letters' category. cf. A GUIDE TO THE BIBLE
>   | Antonio Fuentes